# Does Quick Deploy deploy directly from the source org, or from a snapshot?

Tags: quick-deploy

I couldn't find any immediate answers when I Googled this, so I'm providing a Q&A style post for posterity.

If I validate a change set from my sandbox to production, then I make a change to one of the elements (for instance, an Apex class) in the change set in my sandbox, what will be deployed when I use the Quick Deploy feature...

- A snapshot of the element as it was when I validated the change set? OR...
- The updated element that now lives in my sandbox?

Answer (score 2):

I tested this myself by updating an Apex class after validating a change set that included it, then deploying the change set. Apparently...

**A snapshot of the element as it was when I validated the change set** will be deployed.